# Grails can't see axis-1.4.jar

Tags: grails, axis

Sorry I know I'm new and bad at programming, here is my problem :

My Grails cant see the axis-1.4.jar even if its defined in `buildconfig.groovy` and placed in the **lib** folder.

**What have I done:**

I verified the `axis-1.4.jar` and it contains the `TypeMappingRegistryImpl.class`

Here the result :

```
| Error 2013-03-06 11:17:58,786 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/SpagoJEEGrails]  - StandardWrapper.Throwable
Message: org/apache/axis/encoding/TypeMappingRegistryImpl
    Line | Method
->>  449 | <init>          in org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    139 | setDocument     in org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument
|     65 | <init> . . . .  in     ''
|    179 | configureEngine in org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider
|    172 | init . . . . .  in org.apache.axis.AxisEngine
|    156 | <init>          in     ''
|     88 | <init> . . . .  in org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer
|    109 | createServer    in org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory
|     73 | getServer . . . in     ''
|    185 | getEngine       in org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase
|    396 | getOption . . . in     ''
|    112 | init            in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run             in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingRegistryImpl
->>  217 | run             in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    205 | findClass       in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    321 | loadClass . . . in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    266 | loadClass       in     ''
|    449 | <init> . . . .  in org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment
|    139 | setDocument     in org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument
|     65 | <init> . . . .  in     ''
|    179 | configureEngine in org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider
|    172 | init . . . . .  in org.apache.axis.AxisEngine
|    156 | <init>          in     ''
|     88 | <init> . . . .  in org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer
|    109 | createServer    in org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory
|     73 | getServer . . . in     ''
|    185 | getEngine       in org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase
|    396 | getOption . . . in     ''
|    112 | init            in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run             in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-03-06 11:17:58,843 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/SpagoJEEGrails]  - Servlet /SpagoJEEGrails threw load() exception
Message: org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingRegistryImpl
    Line | Method
->>  217 | run             in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    205 | findClass       in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    321 | loadClass . . . in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    266 | loadClass       in     ''
|    449 | <init> . . . .  in org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment
|    139 | setDocument     in org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument
|     65 | <init> . . . .  in     ''
|    179 | configureEngine in org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider
|    172 | init . . . . .  in org.apache.axis.AxisEngine
|    156 | <init>          in     ''
|     88 | <init> . . . .  in org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer
|    109 | createServer    in org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory
|     73 | getServer . . . in     ''
|    185 | getEngine       in org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase
|    396 | getOption . . . in     ''
|    112 | init            in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run             in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1146 | runWorker . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/SpagoJEEGrails
| Error 2013-03-06 11:20:00,897 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR common.SsoServiceFactory  - Error occurred
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   55 | getConfigValue     in it.eng.spagobi.commons.SingletonConfig
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     44 | createProxyService in it.eng.spagobi.services.common.SsoServiceFactory
|    151 | findUserId . . . . in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.ProfileFilter
|     71 | doFilter           in     ''
|     82 | doFilter . . . . . in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter
|   1146 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run                in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-03-06 11:20:00,905 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR filters.ProfileFilter  - java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error 2013-03-06 11:20:01,932 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR utilities.GeneralUtilities  - Error while recovering SpagoBI context address
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   55 | getConfigValue    in it.eng.spagobi.commons.SingletonConfig
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    657 | getSpagoBiContext in it.eng.spagobi.commons.utilities.GeneralUtilities
|    104 | _jspService . . . in org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.commons.sessionExpired_jsp
|     70 | service           in org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
|    432 | service . . . . . in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper
|    390 | serviceJspFile    in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
|    334 | service . . . . . in     ''
|    146 | route             in it.eng.spago.dispatching.httpchannel.Router
|     91 | render . . . . .  in it.eng.spago.presentation.rendering.AbstractServletModelRenderer
|    546 | render            in it.eng.spago.dispatching.httpchannel.AdapterHTTP
|    449 | service . . . . . in     ''
|    109 | doFilter          in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.ProfileFilter
|     82 | doFilter . . . .  in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter
|   1146 | runWorker         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run               in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-03-06 11:20:01,937 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR utilities.GeneralUtilities  - Error while recovering SpagoBI context address
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   55 | getConfigValue    in it.eng.spagobi.commons.SingletonConfig
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    657 | getSpagoBiContext in it.eng.spagobi.commons.utilities.GeneralUtilities
|    117 | _jspService . . . in org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.commons.sessionExpired_jsp
|     70 | service           in org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
|    432 | service . . . . . in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper
|    390 | serviceJspFile    in org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
|    334 | service . . . . . in     ''
|    146 | route             in it.eng.spago.dispatching.httpchannel.Router
|     91 | render . . . . .  in it.eng.spago.presentation.rendering.AbstractServletModelRenderer
|    546 | render            in it.eng.spago.dispatching.httpchannel.AdapterHTTP
|    449 | service . . . . . in     ''
|    109 | doFilter          in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.ProfileFilter
|     82 | doFilter . . . .  in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter
|   1146 | runWorker         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run               in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-03-06 11:20:02,229 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR common.SsoServiceFactory  - Error occurred
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   55 | getConfigValue     in it.eng.spagobi.commons.SingletonConfig
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     44 | createProxyService in it.eng.spagobi.services.common.SsoServiceFactory
|    151 | findUserId . . . . in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.ProfileFilter
|     71 | doFilter           in     ''
|     82 | doFilter . . . . . in it.eng.spagobi.commons.filters.SpagoBICoreCheckSessionFilter
|   1146 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run                in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-03-06 11:20:02,233 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR filters.ProfileFilter  - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thx for help :)

Comment: Just in case: have you run refresh-dependencies?

Comment: I did : grails clean.
what is refresh-dependencies ?

Comment: It should add to your local jar cache all jars which your application depends on. (It's also described in the docs).

Comment: Yes I have all the jars needed, and I have the axis-1.4.jar, but I dont understand why Grails can see all other jars and not the axis one :'(, thx for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by others, try the following in this order.

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
grails run-app
```

The above should be enough to solve your problems.

It would also be good to indicate the version of Grails that you're using in general.

Comment: Thx for help :) , I would like to give u +1, but they say "need 15 reputation to vote" .....